# SparkFun BMP581 sensor is not working with an Adafruit with a TCA9548a multiplexer - Arduino

Tags: arduino, sensor, multiplexer

I am trying to get a [SparkFun BMP581](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/qwiic-pressure-sensor-bmp581-hookup-guide?_ga=2.46595239.1678791439.1666613160-387690318.1655988316#introduction) sensor to work with an [Adafruit TCA9548a multiplexer](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2717). The BMP581 works when it is not connected to the TCA. The inverse happens when the they are connected.

Code w/o TCA9548:

```
#include "SparkFun_BMP581_Arduino_Library.h"
#include <Wire.h>

BMP581 pressureSensor; // Create a new sensor object

uint8_t i2cAddress = BMP581_I2C_ADDRESS_DEFAULT;

void setup() {
  Wire.begin(); // Start I2C bus
  delay(500);   // wait
  Serial.begin(115200); // Start Serial connection

  Serial.println("BMP581 Begin!");
  
  /* Initialize the sensor */
  while (pressureSensor.beginI2C(i2cAddress) != BMP5_OK) {
    // Not connected --> inform user
    Serial.println("Error: BMP581 not connected - check wiring and I2C address!");

    // Wait
    delay(1000);
  }
  Serial.println("BMP581 Connected!");
}

void loop() {
  // Get measurements from the sensor
  bmp5_sensor_data data = {0};
  int8_t err = pressureSensor.getSensorData(&data);
  
  // Check whether data was acquired successfully
  if (err == BMP5_OK) {
    Serial.print("Temperature (C): ");
    Serial.print(data.temperature);
    
    Serial.print("\nPressure (Pa): ");
    Serial.println(data.pressure);
  }
  else {
    Serial.print("Error getting data from sensor! Error Code: ");
    Serial.println(err);
  }
  delay(1000);
}
```

Code w/ TCA9548:

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include "SparkFun_BMP581_Arduino_Library.h"

BMP581 BMP;

#define TCA_Addr 0x70
uint8_t BMP_Addr = BMP581_I2C_ADDRESS_DEFAULT;

void tcaselect(uint8_t i) {
  if (i > 7) return;

  Wire.beginTransmission(TCA_Addr);
  Wire.write(1 << i);
  Wire.endTransmission();
}

void setup() {
  while (!Serial);
  delay(1000);
  Wire.begin();
  Serial.begin(115200);

  tcaselect(5);
  init_bmp();
}

void loop() {
  bmp581();
}

void init_bmp() {
  tcaselect(5);
  while (BMP.beginI2C(TCA_Addr) != BMP5_OK) {
    Serial.println("Error: BMP581 not connected - check wiring and I2C address!");
    delay(1000);
  }
  Serial.println("BMP581 Connected!");
}

void bmp581() {
  tcaselect(5);
  bmp5_sensor_data data = {0};
  int8_t err = BMP.getSensorData(&data);

  if (err == BMP5_OK) {
    Serial.print("Temperature (C): ");
    Serial.println(data.temperature);

    Serial.print("\nPressure (Pa): ");
    Serial.println(data.pressure);
  }
  else {
    Serial.print("Error getting data from sensor! Error Code: ");
    Serial.println(err);
  }
  delay(1000);
}
```

I don't have Fritzing so please bear with me and my circuit diagram I drew in paint.

[image: Circuit Diagram]

Comment: I am using an Arduino Uno by the way, technically it's an Elego Uno.

Comment: Please understand you can't see what the problem is by drawing a block and wiring diagram. Those are not just blocks or chips, they are modules with other details too. For example if each module has a set of pull-ups on each input and output, you have six sets of pull-ups already on the bus, which can be too strong for the whole bus, and it stops working at the moment you select the bus 5. Figure out the module schematics and draw in the details.